# Powershell Not Expanding Variable String inside Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to template some strings using Powershell string expansion. When I use a string literal it's fine, but when I pass the string as a variable it doesn't work. What do I need to do differently?

```powershell
$list = Get-Process

# this works fine
$list | ForEach-Object {"$($_.ProcessName)"}

# this doesn't
$template = "$($_.ProcessName)"
$list | ForEach-Object {$template}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `$template` there? It doesn't hold what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with just a normal string.  However, you could put the string inside a [scriptblock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms583275.aspx) and then invoke it with the [call operator `&`](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html):

```powershell
$template = {"$($_.ProcessName)"}
$list | ForEach-Object {&$template}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the first problem.

After you run `$template = "$($_.ProcessName)"` you expect the value of `$template` to be the string `$($_.ProcessName)` but it isn't.

```
> $template = "$($_.ProcessName)"
> "[" + $template + "]"
[]
```

The expression in the double quotes was evaluated (and became the empty string).

You need to prevent that by using single quotes.

```
> $template = '$($_.ProcessName)'
> "[" + $template + "]"
[$($_.ProcessName)]
```

Ok. So let's try that in your foreach loop?

```
> $list = Get-Process
> $template = '$($_.ProcessName)'
> $list | ForEach-Object {$template}
$($_.ProcessName)
$($_.ProcessName)
$($_.ProcessName)
$($_.ProcessName)
...
```

Hm... not what we wanted exactly either. That's because powershell isn't evaluating the string as an expression. So we need to force it to do that.

You can do that with `Invoke-Expression`.

```
> $list = Get-Process
> $template = '$($_.ProcessName)'
> $list | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Expression $template}
procA
procB
procC
...
```

(You can also use a scriptblock as iCodez indicates in their answer. I can't comment on the relative merits of one approach over the other. I think the scriptblock is likely to be more extensible and useful in general though.)

Comment: Good explanation, but regarding whether to prefer a script block vs. `Invoke-Expression`: like `eval` in POSIX-like shells, [`Invoke-Expression` is considered "harmful"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), and avoiding it is a good habit to form when other (often better) solutions are available.

Answer (score 1):

At the point that you are generating the string in `$template`,  `$_` doesn't exist. Therefore, you are getting an empty string.

You would be better off using:

```
$template = "{0}"
$list | ForEach-Object { $template -f $_.ProcessName }
```

This uses .NET's string.Format templating. The argument passed to `-f` is an array of objects, so if you want more you can just comma separate them:

```
"{0}-{1}" -f "One", "Two"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also force the string expansion.  You'll need to define the string with single quotes so it isn't expanded at that point, and then in the loop use this:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

For what you're doing, the other answers are probably preferable.  I use this if I don't know up front what variables are in the template so using -f isn't really an option.